# How to upload multiple images into amazon AWS S3 bucket using Node/Angular/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, amazon-web-services

I want to know how and where E-commerce sites upload their product's images.
How good will be Amazon AWS S3 bucket?

How we can upload/get multiple images at one go using Node/Javascript/Angular.

Kindly suggest.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hey you can use AWS S3 client libraries http://aws.amazon.com/code it supports multiple languages.

Alternatively you can also use check out [Minio](https://www.minio.io)Its Open Source, with AWS S3 compatible API. [disclaimer: I work there]

We have a javascript client library which will support all the operations like create, delete, List, PresignedURL options with AWS S3.

Example code: https://github.com/minio/minio-js/tree/master/examples